# Plot bar chart with plotly from group_by() of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have some data and I want to plot it as a bar chart using `Plotly`. My problem is if I previously use `group_by()` from `Pandas` because it says it can't find the column that I had use to group the data.

Using `Pandas` and `Matplotlib` I obtain my goal.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myTrades.csv')
balance = balance.drop(['Price','Fee','Ex Id','Id','Amount'], 1)
balance.loc[balance['Type'] == 'BUY', 'Total'] = -balance['Total']
balance = balance.groupby(['Market']).sum().sort_values('Total',ascending=False)

balance.plot(kind='bar', title='BALANCE CRIPTOMONEDAS', ylabel='USDT', xlabel='SÍMBOLO', figsize=(6, 5))
```

[image]

But with `Plotly` appears an error that says,

> ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['Price', 'Amount', 'Total', 'Fee', 'Ex Id', 'Id'] but received: Market.

This is my code,

```
import plotly.express as px

balance.loc[balance['Type'] == 'BUY', 'Total'] = -balance['Total']
balance = balance.groupby(['Market']).sum().sort_values('Total',ascending=False)

fig = px.bar(balance, x='Market', y='Total')
fig.show()
```

Comment: try this: `balance.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: @r-beginners works with `inplace=False`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have simulated your dataframe as you do not provide sample data
- simple case of `reset_index()` to make **Market** a column to make it work

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 100
balance = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=n), "Type":np.random.choice(["BUY","SELL","Total"],n),
             "Market":np.random.choice(["MATICUSDT","SOLUSDT","VETUSDT","ADAUSDT","DOTUSDT","BNBUSDT","OGNUSDT","BITCUSDT"],n),
             "Total":np.random.uniform(3,100, n)})

balance.loc[balance['Type'] == 'BUY', 'Total'] = -balance['Total']
balance = balance.groupby(['Market']).sum().sort_values('Total',ascending=False)

fig = px.bar(balance.reset_index(), x='Market', y='Total')
fig.show()
```

[image]